# ClassCastException TextSwitcher to Adview

Tags: java, android

My xml layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C5C6E1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId=""
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drag to set font size" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="25" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/questionTEXT"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/titlefav"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
            android:lines="15" >
        </TextSwitcher>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/titlefav"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tipText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Swipe for more quotes"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/f_disable" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId=""
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to get the textswitcher as:
tv = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

I get the following exception:

android.widget.TextSwitcher cannot be cast to com.google.ads.AdView. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Eclipse probably fumbled while generating your `R.java` file. A `project clean` should fix this. Select your project then go to `Project`->`Clean`.

Comment: @Torcellite, you got it right. pls. post this comment as answer and I shall accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse probably fumbled while generating your `R.java` file. A project clean should fix this. Select your project then go to `Project->Clean`.